# HTML CSS IE and Firefox Overflow property conflicting

Tags: html, css

I wish to set a table to a fixed height and then for rows extending beyond the height, to show a scrollbar. If the rows do not extend beyond the height of the table i still wish to show a scrollbar but obviously its not scrollable.

I'm doing testing on IE7 and it only appears to like overflow:scroll, but when i test in Firefox no scroll is visible.

Does anybody know any code, including css-only-for-IE code which would solve this problem please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that only the elements with `block` display allow to set their `overflow` property.

Comment: @rhino is correct. overflow is not to be used for the table element.

Answer (score 0):

You could include the data part of `table` in `div`

```
<table id="table-header">
  <th>
  ..
  </th>
</table>
<div id="table-scrollbar">
  <table>
  ..
  </table>
<table>
```

And then just set add css for the div (and possibly for the table, so cells have the same width)

```
#table-scrollbar { overflow: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds something like this, no? http://fixedheadertable.com/demo/fullwindowdemo.html